# MDX Dynamic Set Filter Measuers

Tags: mdx

I am new to MDX.
I want to create a Dynamic Set on SSAS (SQL Server 2014) where this Set filters all  Measures 
where Measure Date is greater than the current selected date.

Is this possible with a Dynamic Set if not which other solutions are possible?

```
   ID|Date      |MeasureVal
   1 |15.01.2014| 100
   2 |16.01.2014| 150
   3 |20.02.2014| 500
   4 |21.02.2014| 150
```

So when the User select this Set and the Date Filter is on 16.01.2014 it should show return Measures with Date greater than 16.01.2014. 
From the above example it should return Measures with ID 3,4

Here is my Try

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[MyTestSet]
 AS  
  Filter (
  [Production Time].[Time Hierarchy].[Date].AllMembers , 
  ( [Production Time].[Time Hierarchy].[Date].CurrentMember.member_caption > "Current selected Date?" )
   ;
```

Comment: please add your attempted mdx script

Comment: do you use `SSAS` and any third party tool like `Mondrian`?

Comment: i am using SSAS, SQL Server  2014. There are no third party tool. As frontend we would prefere Excell 2010

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[MyTestSet]
 AS     Filter(
          [Production Time].[Time Hierarchy].[Date].Members as dtSet,
          dtSet.Item(
            dtSet.CurrentOrdinal-1
          ).member_caption > "Current selected Date?"
        );
```

But I don't think `member_caption` will return a number so how will `>` function?

Usually if you want a set of dates greater than a specified member in `mdx` you use the range operator, which is a colon `:` couple with a `null` on one side of the colon. So here are two example:

```
WITH 
SET [GreaterThanX] AS
  {
    [Production Time].[Time Hierarchy].[Date].[01 Jan 2014]
   :
    null
  }
SET [LessThanX] AS
  {
    null
   :
    [Production Time].[Time Hierarchy].[Date].[01 Jan 2014]
  }
SELECT
  {} ON 0,
  [GreaterThanX] ON 1
  //[LessThanX] ON 1
FROM myCube;
```

Try the above - the first should give you all dates after 01 Jan whereas the second all dates less than.
note: when using the `:` operator it is important that the specified member, in this case `[Production Time].[Time Hierarchy].[Date].[01 Jan 2014]` exists in the cube - if it doesn't exist no error occur but the expression is evaluated as `null:null` i.e. all dates will be returned.